# post reaction to message in microsoft bot framework

Tags: botframework

I have developped a Microsoft Bot that needs to post a reaction to a message in a Team Channel.
I have the correct structure for the activity to post but I can't find the endpoint for posting the reaction.

[image]

```
                activity.ReplyToId = id;
                activity.Id = id;
                activity.Type = "message";
                string channelUrl = $"https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea/v3/conversations/{targetChannelId}/activities/{id}";
                var stringContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(activity), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                HttpResponseMessage respons = await targetLayer.PostMessageUsingBotApi(channelUrl, stringContent);
                string result = await respons.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

When I receive a reaction change, the activityType is messageReaction.
I try to post it to this endpoint ([https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea/v3/conversations/{targetChannelId}/activities/{id}](https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea/v3/conversations/%7BtargetChannelId%7D/activities/%7Bid%7D)) I got an error saying that messageReaction is an invalid action type.
If I replace messageReaction by message and then Post it, it then replies that the activity is invalid (missing Text or attachment).

How do I simply post a reaction?